# I got error in lambda function testing with Golang

Tags: go, aws-lambda

```
{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 011445f8-fcf4-4d17-8027-6ad641170efe Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError"
}
```

I got this from Lambda function testing when i test zip file.
and my code is this

```
    package main
 
import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type MyEvent struct {
        Name string `json:"What is your name?"`
        Age int     `json:"How old are you?"`
}
 
type MyResponse struct {
        Message string `json:"Answer:"`
}
 
func HandleLambdaEvent(event MyEvent) (MyResponse, error) {
        return MyResponse{Message: fmt.Sprintf("Hi %s you are %d years old!", event.Name, event.Age)}, nil
}
 
func main() {
        lambda.Start(HandleLambdaEvent)
}
```

in my ubuntu i run it and make it zip file.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the struct. The `json` fields in the struct have to be equal to the one in Input.

```golang
type MyEvent struct {
   Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
   Age int     `json:"age,omitempty"`
}
```